# How to get rss feed auto notification android?

Tags: android

I do not know how to bring rss feed auto notification .Application works well. Xml data rss feed works. I want the rss feed to come as a post notification.

1. I need rss feed autofication merge.

   ```
   private RSSFeed rssFeed = null;
   private ArrayList<RSSItem> postsList;
   private RssAdapter listAdapter;
   private ViewModeUtils viewModeUtils;
   private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

   private Activity mAct;
   private RelativeLayout ll;
   private String url;
   private AdView mAdView;
   private View rootView;
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ll = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_refresh, container, false);
       return ll;
   }

   @Override
   public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
       setHasOptionsMenu(true);

       RecyclerView listView = ll.findViewById(R.id.list);
       postsList = new ArrayList<>();
       listAdapter = new RssAdapter(getContext(), postsList);
       listAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_PROGRESS);
       listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
       listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

       swipeRefreshLayout = ll.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
       swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
           @Override
           public void onRefresh() {
               refreshItems();
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
       mAct = getActivity();
   ```

   //        url = RssFragment.this.getArguments().getStringArray(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_DATA)[0];
   refreshItems();
   }

   ```
   private class RssTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
           try {
               URL rssUrl = new URL("http://www.rssmix.com/u/12847959/rss.xml");
               SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
               SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
               XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
               RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
               myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
               InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
               myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

               rssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();

           } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) {
               Log.printStackTrace(e);
           }

           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           if (rssFeed != null) {
               if (rssFeed.getList().size() > 0) {
                   postsList.addAll(rssFeed.getList());
               }

               listAdapter.setHasMore(false);
               listAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_LIST);
               swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

           } else {
               String message = null;
               if (!url.startsWith("http"))
                   message = "Debug info: '" + url + "' is most likely not a valid RSS url. Make sure the url entered in your configuration starts with 'http' and verify if it's valid XML using https://validator.w3.org/feed/";
               Helper.noConnection(mAct, message);

               listAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_EMPTY);
               swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

           }

           super.onPostExecute(result);
       }

   }

   @Override
   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.rss_menu, menu);
       viewModeUtils = new ViewModeUtils(getContext(), getClass());
       viewModeUtils.inflateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
       ThemeUtils.tintAllIcons(menu, mAct);
   }

   private void refreshItems() {
       postsList.clear();
       listAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_PROGRESS);
       new RssTask().execute();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       viewModeUtils.handleSelection(item, new ViewModeUtils.ChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void modeChanged() {
               listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
       });
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.info:
               //show information about the feed in general in a dialog
               if (rssFeed != null) {
                   String FeedTitle = (rssFeed.getTitle());
                   String FeedDescription = (rssFeed.getDescription());
                   //String FeedPubdate = (myRssFeed.getPubdate()); most times not present
                   String FeedLink = (rssFeed.getLink());

                   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mAct);

                   String titlevalue = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_title_value);
                   String descriptionvalue = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_description_value);
                   String linkvalue = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_link_value);

                   if (FeedLink.equals("")) {
                       builder.setMessage(titlevalue + ": \n" + FeedTitle +
                               "\n\n" + descriptionvalue + ": \n" + FeedDescription);
                   } else {
                       builder.setMessage(titlevalue + ": \n" + FeedTitle +
                               "\n\n" + descriptionvalue + ": \n" + FeedDescription +
                               "\n\n" + linkvalue + ": \n" + FeedLink);
                   }

                   builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), null)
                           .setCancelable(true);
                   builder.create();
                   builder.show();

               }
               return true;
           default:
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Let me know if anyone knows how I get rss feed notification

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a background worker with work manager which is one of the jetpack components in android world. In that worker, if you got new feeds you can show local notifications to the user. Here, use this library to firing the notifications: https://github.com/theozgurr/NotificationMan

And you can see usage of the work manager in it.